# Express Variable Base Routes (REST)

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I'd like to extend "base" REST calls using express but I think I'm running into a limitation (or my lack of understanding). I want all REST endpoints share the same basic REST routes. I don't want to write these for every endpoint service (i.e. planets, stars, etc...)

```
app.get('/api/planet/type',function(req,res) {
     ...
});

app.get('/api/planet/type/:_id',function(req,res) {
    ...
});

app.post('/api/planet/type',function(req,res) {
    ...
});

app.patch('/api/planet/type/:_id',function(req,res){
    ...
});

app.delete('/api/planet/type/:_id',function(req,res) {  
    ...     
});
```

What I'd prefer to do is use a variable in my implementing module

```
require('base-rest')('/api/planet/type',planet-model);
require('base-rest')('/api/star/type',star-model);
```

Then use a variable for the base endpoint, but it appears express can handle dynamic routes at runtime.

```
app.get(baseURL,function(req,res) {
     ...
});

app.get(baseURL+'/:_id',function(req,res) {
    ...
});
```

Is this possible? If so, how can I achieve this?

Please note, I'm using Express v4

Comment: So I'm guessing this is not possible? Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can in fact be done (with caveats). This is somewhat outlined by Hage's post.

```
//base.js

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
....
router.get('/:id', function(req, res) {
    ....
});
//Additional routes here

module.exports = router
```

The implementation file

```
//planets.js
var base = require('./base');
app.use('/api/planets',base);
```

Full details found here: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

There is a caveat to this however. I cannot reuse base.js for multiple implementations since node.js by default uses singletons for `require('./base')`. This means you will get the same instance when I really want a new instance. Why? Because I want to inject my model for each base route.

For Example:

```
var model = null;
module.exports.map = function(entity) {
    model = entity;
}

router.get('/:id', function(req, res) {
    model.findOne(...) //using mongoose here
});
```

The same model will be used for all routes across multiple modules since the `require('./base')` is a singleton import.

***If anyone knows a solution of this additional problem, let me know!!!***

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Answer (score 1):

Probably you want to do something like this:

```
var planet = express.Router()
planet.get('/type', function (req, res) { ... })
planet.get('/type/:id', function (req, res) { ... })
planet.post('/type', function (req, res) { ... })
planet.post('/type/:id', function (req, res) { ... })
planet.delete('/type/:id', function (req, res) { ... })

app.use('/api/planet', planet)
```

Export the router as a local node module.